# Transaction History using Python

Tags: python

First of all, I created a bank account for withdrawing money, depositing, and seeing the balance and now I want to add transaction history when users add money or withdraw here's what I've tried but I didn't succeed. Any help?

```python
class BankAccount:
    
    def __init__(self,name,accountNumber,salary):
        self.name = name
        self.accountNumber = accountNumber
        self.salary = salary
        list = []

    def description(self):
        print("Name is: " , self.name)
        print("AccountNumber is: " , self.accountNumber)
        print("Salay is: " , self.salary)

    def deposit(self,deposit):
        self.salary = self.salary + deposit
        list.append(deposit)

    def withdraw(self,withdraw):
        self.salary = self.salary - withdraw 
        list.append(withdraw)

    def transaction_history(self,withdraw,deposit):
        list.append(deposit)
        list.append(withdraw)

bank = BankAccount("John" , 420402 , 5000)     
bank.deposit(500)
```

Comment: don't call a  list variable list. then when you have changed you variable name to, for example, transactions, just do `print(self.transactions)`

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good practice to declare a variable which is already the name of a class in Python. That being said, you can declare two new variables `self.deposit_history` and `self.withdraw_history` in the `__init__` function as:

```python
def __init__(self,name,accountNumber,salary):
    self.name = name
    self.accountNumber = accountNumber
    self.salary = salary
    self.deposit_history = []
    self.withdraw_history = []
```

and append these lists in respective functions as:

```python
def deposit(self,deposit):
    self.salary = self.salary + deposit
    self.deposit_history.append(deposit)

def withdraw(self,withdraw):
    self.salary = self.salary - withdraw
    self.withdraw_history.append(withdraw)
```

and finally print them in `transaction_history()` as:

```python
def transaction_history(self):
    print("Deposits: ", self.deposit_history)
    print("Withdraws: ", self.withdraw_history)
```

Output:

```
>>> bank = BankAccount("John" , 420402 , 5000)
>>> bank.deposit(500)
>>> bank.withdraw(300)
>>> bank.transaction_history()
Deposits:  [500]
Withdraws:  [300]
>>> bank.description()
Name is:  John
AccountNumber is:  420402
Salary is:  5200
```